Implementation of async function rate limiter using javascript
I am working on a problem of rate limiter, the context is we have to implement this in javascript,

can allow N asycn functions work in the same time.
have to execute all the functions in order.

For example, if we have tasks of [1,2,3,4,5], each function is async, we have the limit of 2. Now we have to execute 1,2 first, then wait until one of the tasks has been finished, we can execute next task, which is 3.
I have done the following code, however, not sure how to continue to execute the 3 once 1, 2 has been done. Can anyone help?
let activeFunc = 0;
const mapLimit = (inputs, limit, iteratee, finalCallback) => {
    // code

    for (let i = 0; i < limit - activeFunc && inputs.length > 0; i++) {
        activeFunc++; // add a thread
        let cur = inputs.shift();
        call(cur, iteratee)
            .then(done(cur, finalCallback));
    }
}

const done = (val, finalCallback) => {
    finalCallback(val + "user");
    activeFunc--;
}

const call = (val, iteratee) => {
    console.log(`Starting ${val}`);
    return new Promise(resolve => iteratee(val, resolve));
}

const mockFunction = (input, callback) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(input);
    }, Math.random() * 500);
}

mapLimit([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 3, mockFunction, (result) => console.log(result))

I have tried to use the Promise to solve the problem, but it seems like the for loop can not go back to execute?

What exactly is the point here? An asynchronous operation only runs when it isn't waiting on external activity. You can have 1000 asynchronous tasks "active" without using up any CPU time (well hardly any), while whatever they're waiting for happens somewhere else.

yes, just want to implement a function that limits N async function running in the same time.

The thing is, there's only one thread. Launching an asynchronous function does not start a concurrent thread or process.

correct, the 1,2,3 tasks refer to some tasks like download that could return async results.

It's probably easier to implement a "rate" limiter by deciding on a per-second (or per-whatever) allocation, then you can use timers (which are cheap) to schedule operations at allotted time slots.

You would need to trigger the next task where you are currently doing activeFunc--.

How could I do that?

I'd just use async-q (https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q). You can use eachLimit() or mapLimit() or parallelLimit() for this.
